# Input field issue in laravel form submission

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5, laravel-6

I'm trying to add error display class to my laravel form field

My form:

```
{!! Form::open(array('route' => 'users.store','method'=>'POST')) !!}
<div class="container mt-3">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <strong>First Name:</strong>
            {!! Form::text('name', null, array('placeholder' => 'First Name','class' => 'form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror')) !!}
            @error('name')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

The form was working fine until I changed the filed class to

```
'class' => 'form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror'
```

as I needed to display the error message under the input field.

But when I run the application it gives me an error saying,

```
syntax error, unexpected 'name' (T_STRING), expecting ')'
```

So What I'm doing wrong and how can I fix that?

Also

How can I set old value correctly in that field??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following snippet will works

```
{!! Form::text('name', null, $attributes = $errors->has('name') ? array('placeholder' => 'First Name', 'class' => 'form-control has-error') : array('placeholder' => 'First Name', 'class' => 'form-control')) !!}
```

We will need to create two arrays one for error and another for not an error.

Comment: I hope the above solution is works for you. Or you should tell us in case of any error